# Find $x$ for random variable with 15 degrees of freedom

Tags: probability, random-variables, chi-squared

I have a question stating:

If $X$ is a chi-square random variable with 15 degrees of freedom, find the value of $x$ such that $P(X >= x) = 0.05$.

The answer in the book is $0.05$.  I am confused why the variable $x$ would be equal to $0.05$ in the statement $P(X >= x) = 0.05$ rather than being equal to a value from a chi-square table for $\chi^2$<sub>15, 0.05</sub>

Comment: I believe the answer in the book is a typo.  I looked up the value of $x$ using a chi-square table.

Answer (score 0):

According to R, the value of $x$ is 24.99579.

```
> qchisq(0.95,15)
[1] 24.99579
```